# Kinect for Windows Version 1 Documentation

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Does anyone know where or how to get documentation for version 1 of the Kinect SDK - I downloaded Kinect for Windows V1.8 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278) in order to develop a tool to use a first gen Kinect camera on a windows 7 machine but after installation it turns out that even though Microsoft are continuing to serve the old SDK installation files the documentation was hosted online and the links to that are now redirected to a [generic landing page for previous version docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/#SDK_1pt8) which doesn't seem to include the Kinect pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so the most comprehensive link into the internet archives for the Kinect documentation is [going back to around 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904052951/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/hh855347.aspx) which mostly documents Kinect for Windows SDK 1.6 ... there are partial archives going forward to version 1.8 however its a lot more hit and miss whether specific pages are in the archive. The version linked seems to have most if not all the C++ reference intact.

**Note** *To save anyone reading the comments below from having to uninstall and reinstall just to access the documentation files the following link is a copy of the CHM files in my Dropbox [Windows SDK v1.0 windows chm,chi help files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wl68vjzj4hubb1e/AACw5DFwUDk_CsSxywHdptYga?dl=0)*

Comment: The original Kinect for Windows SDK v1.0 installer downloadable from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28782 contains a full set of the v1.0 documentation which at least gives some bearings - minus whatever changed in subsequent releases... docs were dropped from subsequent installers in favour of online documentation - Oops.

Comment: Note that you need to uninstall other versions of SDK before installing v1.0 or it wont copy files... once done you get a Windows chm help file that you can copy somewhere safe before updating to the later SDK.

Comment: MS has restored a version of the 1.8 docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect-1.8/hh855347(v=ieb.10)